# Scala Parsing RSS/Atom feeds

Tags: java, scala, rss, feed, atom-feed

Does anyone know a good library/jar to parse RSS/Atom Feeds?

I'd like to stuff a URL in, and want to get the news-items in a homogenous way. (Means: it should not matter whether the Source contains an Atom or RSS feed. I just want "Items" back.)

After browsing on SO, I came up with ROME, but it seems to be chaotic at the moment (no download for example), and is a pure Java solution. Scala would be preferred, but Java is quite okay if nothing Scala-specific exists. Also, it should be a single JAR Library, since I don't use Maven etc.

PS: It's not for Android, just for a good old desktop app.

EDIT: To be more clear, I already know how to get the content from resources as XML. I want to parse them! Autodetect whether it's Atom or some RSS and give me back a uniform list of items.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked out [Dispatch](http://dispatch.databinder.net/Dispatch.html)?  It doesn't have any RSS/Atom features built in *per se*, but you should be able to handle the response text as a `scala.xml.NodeSeq` and do whatever you need.

Comment: Okay, i think my question was not exact enough. Getting some Content from the Web into XML is no problem from scala for me. I'd like to have to _parse_ the content. I don't want to reinvent the wheel, fizzling out whether its atom or rss and give me the "items" in an uniform dataset, this is what I want :)